# How to display hidden placeholder without refreshing the page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two placeholders in one page and basically my requirement is that I want to show other placeholder on click of button which is in first placeholder without refreshing the page.

But when I m clicking on the button in 1st placeholder it is refreshing the page and then showing me second placeholder.I m open to hear any other suggestions also if it is not possible through placeholder.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, as suggested, use an `UpdatePanel`.  As long as you ensure that both PlaceHolders exist within the `ContentTemplate` element, you will be able to switch between the PlaceHolders without the whole page being refreshed.

However, such convenience comes at the cost of control.  This isn't a knock on Microsoft.  The same problems exist for most ready-rolled solutions.

Whatever route you choose, you're going to need something to refresh *part* of the current page's DOM.  And really, this means Javascript.

Do the actions in PlaceHolder 1 change the content of PlaceHolder 2?  If not, you could render both, and simply use CSS to make PlaceHolder 2 invisible on load.  You could then use Javascript events to make it visible as desired.

If actions on PlaceHolder 1 *do* affect PlaceHolder 2, then the above solution won't work, as you'll need to work out what PlaceHolder 2 is going to contain before displaying it.

The real question is whether you employ your own Javascript ( possibly in conjunction with a mature js library like mootools or jQuery ), and maybe learn something in the process, or run with the ASP .NET AJAX stuff for the quick solution, and hope you don't run into any problems.

Comment: Thats what I wanted. Hiding through css and displaying using javascript it seems to be the nice idea....Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap an updatepanel around you PlaceHolder:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="placeholder">hello</asp:PlaceHolder>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        placeholder.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        placeholder.Visible = true;
    }
```

This wil generate a partial postback (via AJAX), so only the content inside my updatepanel gets updated. In the <Triggers>-section, I specify that my Button will trigger the postback.

Comment: This looks great....butthere is no way to avoid scriptmanager rite? Actually we r not using ajax as of now....and I was bit reluctant in doing all the settings for ajax ....If there is any other method to achieve this...?

Comment: No, I'm pretty shure that it's not possible to use the updatepanel without the scriptmanager because the scriptmanager does all the complecated ajax-work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Either use an UpdatePanel control (part of the MS ajax framework) or use JavaScript.  Placeholder would have to render an HTML element, and I'm not sure that it does.  If it doesn't, you can use a panel instead, and then in JS do:

```
function show() {
var panel = document.getElementById("<%= panel2.ClientID %>");
panel.style.display = "true";
}

<asp:Button id="btn1" runat="server" OnClientClick="show();return false;" />
```

HTH.

Comment: PlaceHolder doesn't render an element.  Additionally, if something is set to be invisible server-side, it won't be included in the DOM, so your reference to the client ID will always return null.

Comment: No, if you set it to <asp:Panel id="panel2" runat="server" style="display:none"></asp:Panel>, making it invisible, then that would work.  Should have included that in the original response. Didn't think Placeholder rendered anything... panel would have to be used.